# Obscure "Answer your Question" button when adding a comment

Tags: feature-request

Several times when I've been adding a comment on a question I've posted, I've clicked the "Answer your Question" button instead of the "Add Comment" button, probably because the Answer button is a much bigger target.

It would be cool if, when editing a comment, the "Answer Your Question" button turned into unclickable text that said something like, "Save or cancel your comment to re-enable answering".

Comment: I'd argue that noting should be changed.  I can't imagine that this happens very often.  I think it looks fine, and makes sense the way it currently is.

Answer (score 1):

The "Post and Answer" button is bigger but is much further down the page.   The Add Comment button is really close to the comment button.  So I don't think the button should be disabled when a comment is being added because it would not be clear what was happening when the users decides they want to add an answer instead after halfway into adding a comment.